Add one hot feature to tensorflow model
I'm new to deep learning, I'm creating MMOE model with and adding feature step by step in my init function.
class TIGMMOE(tfrs.Model):
    def __init__(self, use_cross_layer, deep_layer_sizes, num_units, num_shared_experts, projection_dim=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.embedding_dimension = 8

        self._embeddings = {}
    
        #categorical embedding (common to all tasks)
        self._embeddings['category'] = tf.keras.Sequential(
          [tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_total_pcats + 1, 32)
          ],name='cat_emb')
    
        self._embeddings['ptype'] = tf.keras.Sequential(
          [tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_total_ptypes + 1, 128)
          ],name='ptype_emb')

          .
          .
          .
     def call(self, feat_inputs):
        features = feat_inputs
        anchor_embeddings = []
        
        for feat_name in _CONTEXT_FEATURE_KEYS:
            anchor_embeddings.append(features[feat_name])
        
        anchor_embeddings.append(self._embeddings['category'](features['anc_pcat_map']))
        anchor_embeddings.append(self._embeddings['ptype'](features['anc_ptcode_map']))
        
        
        anchor_embeddings = {}
        anchor_embeddings['anc_feat_vec'] = features['anc_feat_vec']
        anchor_embeddings['anc_ptcode_map_emb'] = self._embeddings['category'](features['anc_pcat_map'])
        anchor_embeddings['anc_pcat_map_emb'] = self._embeddings['ptype'](features['anc_ptcode_map'])


Now I want to add another feature x to the model which is in int format and I want to add it as one-hot-encode feature. Can someone tell me how I can add this feature from tfrecords to my model.
